# How to get result to display properly (arrays)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I have created the code below and it all works completely fine my problem is that is will add as it goes along and display everything whereas i just need the last array element i have tried array_pop and the end function to no avail any ides?

```
$Count = 0;
        $file_handle = fopen("test2.txt", "rb");

        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

        $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle); 
        $parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text); 
        $arr = array($parts[8]);


        for($i=0;$i<count($arr);){
         $count = $count + $arr[$i]/1024;
         $results= array($count);



            }        
            echo '<p>';
    print_r($results);
    echo '</p>';


        }



            fclose($file_handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `end()`

```
echo '<p>';
end($results);
echo '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array is numeric, couldn't you simply only display the last element like this:

```
$lastRec=count($results);
print_r($results[$lastRec]);
```